# Reproject non-earth to ITM/ICS

Tags: coordinate-system, mapinfo

I'm trying to convert MapInfo, non-earth projection, layers with data in ITM or ICS (Israel coordinates in meters).

When I do so through Universal Translator with converting to SHP and back again, they sit about 70 meters off of where they actually are, and even the ITM and the ICS layers sit a few meters off from each other.

Is there a way to convert from non-earth meters to the their actual projections without this offset?

Answer (score 1):

When I look in the most recent projection file (the one for MapInfo Pro 15.2), I can see these four Israeli projections defined:

```
"--- Israeli Coordinate Systems ---"
"Reshet Israel Yeshana (kilometers)", 8, 33, 1, 35.2120805, 31.7340969, 1, 170.251555, 126.867909
"Reshet Israel Hadasha (kilometers)", 8, 33, 1, 35.2045169, 31.7343936, 1.0000067, 219.529584, 626.907390
"Reshet Israel Yeshana (meters)", 8, 33, 7, 35.2120805, 31.7340969, 1, 170251.555, 126867.909
"Reshet Israel Hadasha (meters)\p2039", 8, 33, 7, 35.2045169, 31.7343936, 1.0000067, 219529.584, 626907.390
```

As you are working in meters, you might want to use one of the last two.

You say that you are converting from and back into non-earth - I would recommend using one of the defined projections if they meet your needs.

If you want to "move" your data from non-earth to a projected coordinate system, you can do this by exporting to MIF/MID, changing the coordsys statement in the MIF and then reimporting the MIF/MID file into MapInfo Pro.

This would of course require that the coordinates actually are correct for the coordinate system you want them "moved" to.